# Derivation of fluid Power due to Shear stress and normal stress

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

How can it be shown that the

(i) power component of a fluid due to shear stress $S_\tau$

$\dot{W}_{s_\tau} = -2\mu\int_A e_n \cdot (\vec{V} \cdot \dot{S}) dA
 + 2\mu \int_{\forall} (\dot{S} \cdot \nabla)\vec{V} \: d\forall$

(ii) and power component of a fluid due to normal stress $S_n$

$ \dot{W}_{s_p} = - \oint e_n \cdot \vec{V} \: p \: dA$

where 
$\mu $- Kinematic Viscosity  
$e_n $- Normal Vector  
$\vec{V}$ - Velocity 
$dA$ - Area component 
$\dot{S}$ - Rate of Strain Dyadic  
$p$ - pressure of the fluid